# How to track users who blocks the app and remove the application?

Tags: windows, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to track users who blocks the app and (after they blocked it) remove the application through the Graph API facebook?

Comment: The problem is, you're unable to get list of all users which use your app via Graph API. You need to know the user id on the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You can use realtome updates. You can find the documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/